# Visual studio Code Debugger Not Working Fine For My Nodejs App

Tags: node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code

I am trying to use the vs code debugger for my node.js application and all the commands and code but when i apply the break point it goes back to the main files and function of the nodejs and npm files instead of going back step by step to the service and then storage, brake points not working properly for my apis any body can help

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/? 
linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "attach",
        "name": "Attach by Process ID",
        "processId": "${command:PickProcess}"
    },

    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Program",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/app/app.js"
    },
    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch via NPM",
        "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
        "runtimeArgs": [
            "run-script",
            "debug"
        ],
        "port": 9229
    },

    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "My Debugger",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\index.js"
    }
    ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried attaching to a node process?

```
Step 1: Run the code.
Step 2: Press CMD + SHIFT + P then search for "Attach to Node Process" and it will list the running processes.
Step 3: Choose the process you want to attach to.
```

This enables debugging.